# How do I deserialise xml into a DataContract when the XML has had namespaces removed?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I serialise my wcf requests and responses into XML but to save database space, I strip out all non-essential information, so the result is:

```
<someObject>
  <someValue>10</someValue>
</someObject>
```

There are more complex nested properties, the above is just an example.

When I try to deserialise, I get an error saying expecting `someObject, someNamespace` but encountered `someObject, ''`

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Position = 0;
DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
```

Is there an easy way to solve this? Perhaps by not using a `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for DataContractSerializer, there is a version of the constructor that lets you specify the xmlroot and namespace.  Does this do what you  need? [DataContractSerializer Constructor (Type, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404902(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost a week old, but it may help someone if you've already found a solution.

If you know the structure beforehand, you could use the XmlSerializer class.

```
string xml = "<someObject>" +
             "  <someValue>10</someValue>" +
             "</someObject>";

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(someObject));
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

}
```

Here's the supporting class to deserialize it into:

```
[Serializable()]
public class someObject
{
    [XmlElement("someValue")]
    public string someValue { get; set; }
}
```

For more complex XML, you'd have to modify the class that you're using. You can nest classes as well as support arrays/lists.

Comment: Cheers, I think I did try this but the `XmlSerializer` doesn't support `Dictionary` and I think it struggles to deserialize certain types without any meta information.

Comment: Well, you could work around it by using a List<KeyValuePair> then, if you truly need the dictionary you can reconstruct it easily from the list. Or, try this class out: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961